# Rewrite url to url without html ending (.html)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect (301) all urls without .html to .html.
Example:

> example.com/site should be redirected to example.com/site.html

I tried the following:

```
RewriteRule (.+)$ /$1.html [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rule is likely to cause a redirect loop, because it would rewrite the URL even after it has already been redirected.

In your pattern you need to make sure that the URL does not end with `.html` already.

You could use a negated pattern to achieve this:

```
RewriteRule !\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L,R=301]
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to apply this for empty paths (such as in your example) or need to reuse the matches of your pattern, you could use a [RewriteCondition](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteRule (.+)$ $1.html [L,R=301]
```

Note that this is a very simple example which only works for the exact case you described. This would also rewrite URLs ending with `.htm` to `.htm.html`, which might or might not be what you want.